# Make Title field enforce unique values in custom list definition (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, content-type

I have a custom list definition, and I am trying to rename the custom 'Title' field to 'Name' and to make it enforce unique values. First, I referenced it in the custom content type (Elements.xml):

```
<FieldRef ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}"  Name="Title"/>
```

and then in the list template (Schema.xml):

```
<Field ID="{fa564e0f-0c70-4ab9-b863-0177e6ddd247}" Name="Title" DisplayName="Name" Type="Text" AllowDuplicateValues="FALSE" Required="TRUE"></Field>
```

The field is renamed, but I can add list items with the same title. If I go in the field settings page, the Enforce unique values property is set to false. How can I enable it, what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find the solution to this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to make this work you need to add:

```
Required="TRUE" EnforceUniqueValues="TRUE" Indexed="TRUE"
```

And Remove

```
AllowDuplicateValues
```

To your `<Field>` in both the *Elements.xml* and the *Schema.xml* of your list definition.